# Data Not available on custom button click

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, visual-workflow

Created a button which is based on vf page and this vf page will invoke the flow. FYI, We are passing the custom object id to flow as follows,

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract__c">
<flow:interview name="PreNotification_flow" finishLocation="/{!Contract__c.Id}">
    <apex:param name="ContractId" value="{!Contract__c.Id}"/>
</flow:interview>
```

And we need this button to work both Classic and lex

Answer (score 0):

At profile level Check the **Run flows** permission